# SQL Delete query is not working in apache camel

Tags: sql, apache-camel

SQL Delete query is not working in camel, as it stuck at the SQL query and nothing happens. Have tried to execute same query in DB directly, it is working fine as expected.
Below is the glimpse of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="OracleConnection">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="${Oracle.DB.DriverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${Oracle.DB.Url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${Oracle.DB.Username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${Oracle.DB.Password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${Oracle.DB.InitialSize}" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="${Oracle.DB.MaxTotal}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${Oracle.DB.MinIdle}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${Oracle.DB.MaxIdle}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedOnMaintenance" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
        <property name="maxWaitMillis"
            value="${Oracle.DB.MaxWaitMillis}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent" id="sql">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="OracleConnection" />
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="GenerateOTPContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="GenerateOTPMainRoute" streamCache="true">
            <from id="_from1"
                uri="restlet:http://localhost:9092/ESB/dbserviceapi/generateOTP?restletMethod=POST" />
            <setHeader headerName="deleteQuery" id="_setHeader2">
                <simple>sql:DELETE FROM MOBILE_OTP_DETAILS WHERE created_dt &lt; SYSDATE - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <log id="_log2" message="Delete query ${header.deleteQuery}" />
            <recipientList delimiter="~" id="_recipientList2"
                ignoreInvalidEndpoints="true">
                <simple>${header.deleteQuery}</simple>
            </recipientList>
            <onException id="_onException1" useOriginalMessage="true">
                <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log id="_log3"
                    message="ESBUUID : ${exchangeId} Exception occurred in GenerateOTPAdapter : ${exception.stacktrace}" />
            </onException>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I'm using dbcp2, pool2 and camel-sql components to connect to DB.

**Any suggestions please?**

Comment: Does the `<simple>` output appear exactly as you intend? What happens if you make a log statement with that same `<simple>` block - how does it look?

Comment: @vikingsteve, below is the log for that simple statement, after Delete query, it stucks and nothing happens.
Delete query sql:DELETE FROM MOBILE_OTP_DETAILS WHERE CREATED_DT < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE

Answer (score 0):

Have found the issue, I had created my own table but missed to grant the delete permission, so it was not deleting the data in DB from camel components so I granted the permission for my table and it worked.